# Firefox/IE HTML5 Video Dimensions Too Large?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, video, html5-video

I have MP4 videos, all encoded with the same settings. The first 9 work properly in IE, Chrome and Firefox. The 10th video's default dimensions are 5184x3456px. IE and Firefox refuse to render this MP4 in their players, but Chrome continues to work properly like the first 9. Does anybody know if it is because of the larger default dimensions of the video? Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I can confirm that some videos with large dimensions don’t play at all in Firefox. But I don’t think there’s a workaround for you except for downloading the video and playing it in a video player program. That’s probably a bug in the browsers.

Comment: Well ultimately we need them to play at their original dimensions within the browser. Thanks for confirming that this problem does exist, though! Hopefully somebody knows of a solution.

Comment: BTW, this happens with WebMs as well.

Comment: After some tests, max value I can get is 4768x2000, Note that Mac's Preview in Finder also has those same limitations

Comment: I believe that is the same maximum value that Internet Explorer follows, but FF has a much lower limit.

Comment: And if you set the width to 5120 (5K standard) you can go to 1856 height max. (Which is not the same ratio as the first limits I mentionned)